# How to Subclass UIScrollView and override the following method: override to nothing to stop auto scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hello I am trying to override the UIscrollview methode so I can prevent auto scrolling on my scroll view. However I keep getting an error. This is the way i have it in my code. Im not sure exactly what im doing wrong

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    //scrollview outlet
    @IBOutlet var ScrollerScreen: UIScrollView!
}

class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    -(void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated{}
}
```

Comment: Your code is a weird mix of Swift and ObjectiveC, and if you get an error it would be very useful if you told us what error is it. My guess is your ObjC code is not compiling under Swift.

Comment: What part of the code is object c? If you tell me then I will be able to convert it into swift code @EmilioPelaez

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method

```
gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch)
```

and return false when you don't want your scroll view to scroll.